# gpxpy not including extension data - how to fix?

Tags: python, gpx

I am trying to manipulate some Geocaching data, which is stored as a GPX that contains an extension (I think).  I am finding that by reading the GPX with gpxpy, and simply exporting the waypoints back out, it loses this extension data.

Python as follows:

```
center_gpx_file = open("input.gpx")
center_gpx = gpxpy.parse(center_gpx_file)

output_gpx = gpxpy.gpx.GPX()

for waypoint in center_gpx.waypoints:
    output_gpx.waypoints.append(waypoint)

f = output_gpx_file = open("output.gpx", "w")
f.write(output_gpx.to_xml())
f.close()
```

A waypoint in input.gpx looks like:

```
 <wpt lat="12.3456" lon="-123.456">
  <time>2014-01-23T08:00:00Z</time>
  <name>GCsometing</name>
  <desc>Some text(1/1)</desc>
  <url>http://www.geocaching.com/</url>
  <urlname>Full cache name</urlname>
  <sym>Geocache</sym>
  <type>Geocache|Traditional Cache</type>
    <gsak:wptExtension xmlns:gsak="http://www.gsak.net/xmlv1/6">
      <gsak:UserFlag>false</gsak:UserFlag>
      <gsak:Lock>false</gsak:Lock>
      <gsak:DNF>false</gsak:DNF>
      <gsak:Watch>false</gsak:Watch>
      <gsak:UserData></gsak:UserData>
      <gsak:FirstToFind>false</gsak:FirstToFind>
      <gsak:User2></gsak:User2>
      <gsak:User3></gsak:User3>
      <snip>
```

and the output looks like:

```
<wpt lat="12.3456" lon="-123.456">
    <time>2014-01-23T08:00:00Z</time>
    <name>GCsomething</name>
    <desc>Some text(1/1)</desc>
    <url>http://www.geocaching.com/</url>
    <urlname>Full cache name</urlname>
    <sym>Geocache</sym>
    <type>Geocache|Traditional Cache</type>
</wpt>
```

How do I get gpxpy to include the `<gsak:wptExtension .. >` element and children?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an experimental version of gpxpy in the dev branch in https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/tree/dev Try that.